# Topology (Open or closed sets)

Tags: general-topology

I have to find $Int (A), Ext(A), \partial(A), A'$, isolated point and closure of $A$. Is A an open or close set?

$$A=\{(x,f(x)): x \in \mathbb{R},f(x)=x\ \mbox{if}\ x \in \mathbb{Q},f(x)=1-x\ \mbox{if}\ x \in \mathbb{R-Q}\}$$

The problem is that I can't understand what is $A$.
I know that the elements are like this

$(-1/2,-1/2)$

$(1/2,1/2)$

$(\pi,1-\pi)$

$(e,1-e)$

I guees that $Int (A)$ was $\mathbb{R}$ but the $Ext(A)$ is $\varnothing$, and if it is what is the $\partial A$? I'm not sure with this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, $\pi \neq 3.14$ and $e \neq 2.7$.  The points you are trying to describe are $(\pi,1-\pi)$ and $(e,1-e)$.  Second, $A$ is a subset of the plane, not the real line.  It is a subset of the union of two lines, $y=x$ and $y=1-x$.  As such it cannot have an interior.  Every point on the two lines is the limit of both points in $A$ and points in the complement of $A$, so the boundary is all of both lines.  Every point not on the two lines is a positive distance away from them, so is part of the exterior.

Comment: @ So, A is an open set? .With these ideas, so the Int(A)=∅ ,$$Ext(A)={(x,f(x) \not\in f(x)=x nor f(x)=1−x}$$ ∂(A)=points in [x,1−x],A′=[x,1−x] , isolated point={the points between f(x)=x and f(x)=1−x } and closure of A=[x,1−x].

Comment: $A$ is not open because at least one point (actually all of them) is arbitrarily close to points outside $A$.  There are no isolated points because every point of $A$ is close to another point of $A$.

Comment: Oh ok, and are the others right?

Comment: It is neither open nor closed.

Comment: So? What is it?

Comment: Many sets are neither open nor closed.   Once you say that you are done on this point.

Comment: I didn't know about it. Thank you. so the answer I give you lbelow the only wrong is the isolated points? There are not, anothers are wrong too?

Comment: No, the answer in the first comment is completely wrong.  It is hard to understand, but I give the interior, exterior, boundary and closure in my original answer.

Comment: Mmm why? the int A =∅, ∂(A) are the points that f(x)=x and f(x)=1-x do , and the ext A is the anothers points in the plane, aren't they, the closure of A is the same that ∂(A), there isn't isolated points and A'=?

Comment: Yes, $int A=\emptyset$.  The boundary is the two lines $y=x$ and $y=1-x$.  Your statement misses $(\pi, \pi)$ because $f(\pi)=1-\pi$ but it is on the boundary because there are points approaching it in $A$ and also points  not in $A$ approaching it.

Comment: mmmm ok I only have a question I read that if closure of A is A then A is a closed set, and what is A'? It's A or it's ∅?

Comment: It is true that if the closure of a set is the set itself, the set is closed. What do you mean by $A'?$  I had thought it was the complement of $A$, but it seems to be the derived set.  In this case, it is the same as the closure of $A$ because all the points of $A$ are also limit points of $A$.

Comment: so, why the set can be closed if the closure is the  set  itself, yes it's the derived set.

Comment: That is one definition of a closed set-one that includes all its limit points.  The interval $[0,1]$ is an example.  It is closed and its closure is the set itself.  Another definition is that a closed set is the complement of an open set.  In the usual topology of the reals these definitions coincide.

Comment: Ok, but you tell me that this set isn't open nor close, but is close for the closure

Comment: I don't understand "is close for the closure".  The closure of a set is always a closed set.  As I said, the closure is two intersecting lines.  $A$ is missing many of the points of those lines, like $(\pi, \pi)$